# Fetch job names associated with a particular Jenkins slave

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way to fetch all the job names associated with a particular Jenkins slave?

I am trying to configure a job to clean workspaces of jobs after the builds are finished. In this job configuration, I have configured a build trigger that checks for an upstream job:

[image]

I want this job to be able to be triggered by all the jobs that are running on a particular slave. Is there a way I can store all the project names that are running on a particular slave, in a parameter/variable and pass that as `Projects to watch`?

Comment: If your real goal is to clean the job's workspace after a build runs, then perhaps the [Workspace Cleanup plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ws-cleanup) can help?

Comment: @DaveBacher it is the goal. But, does this plugin works for slaves? Also we have more than 50 jobs, configuring this plugin in each job will take a long time.